# What does ~= mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax

I've never seen this operator yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the not equal to operator.

In Java and C++ you may have seen it as `!=`

Comment: So easy. Other sites explain it really complicated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It means not equal to. In other languages it is often written as != or <>.

Answer (score 2):

For the documentation see [Relational Operators](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/relationaloperators.html).